# JS : add date obgectto array

Tags: javascript

i try to make array of dates ,but when i push the last one all the other dates in the array be the same last one .

```js
var dateArayy=[];
var date = new Date();


function addone(){
date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); //add day to the date
dateArayy.push(date) ;
// i try also dateArayy[dateArayy.lenght]=date   THE SAME..

}


for (let i=1;i<10;i++){
 addone();
}
console.log(dateArayy)
```

Comment: array of dates will have different dates you mean? but you are not doing anything different for being them different .

Comment: [`Date.prototype.setDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) mutates the `date` object, you need to create a new `Date` for each index.

Comment: date.setDate(date.getDate()+1); //add day to the date

Comment: change addone to: `function addone(i)` and `date.setDate(date.getDate() + i )`

Comment: i see the problem , the date is index on the ram (link of storing data) and it changed to last one... if i use .toDateString() and store it as srting it will work . thank you ...

Comment: in loop: `addone(i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let dates = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
  dates.push(date);
}
console.log(dates);
```

Answer (score 1):

you change and set the same object in array . you should create new `Date` object and add it to the array

```
var dateArayy = [];
var date = new Date();

function addone() {
  var newdate = new Date();
  newdate.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  date = newdate;
  dateArayy.push(date);
}

for (let i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  addone();
}
console.log(dateArayy);
```